# How to construct url of windows shared printer for cups client

Tags: linux, windows, networking, printing, cups

I have a HP laserjet shared on a windows 2003 server as //w3kserver/hp

I want to print from a linux client that has the cups system installed. When I add the printer in the cups web frontend on the linux client I need to provid an url of the printer that is shared on the windows server. How to construct that url for cups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this page](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/samba_reference_guide/29_CUPS-printing_45.html):

```
smb
This backend sends print files to printers shared by a Windows host. Examples 
of CUPS device-URIs that may be used includes:

    smb://workgroup/server/printersharename
    smb://server/printersharename
    smb://username:password@workgroup/server/printersharename
    smb://username:password@server/printersharename

The smb:// backend is a symlink to the Samba utility smbspool (does not ship with
CUPS). If the symlink is not present in your CUPS backend directory, have your 
root user create it: ln -s `which smbspool' /usr/lib/cups/backend/smb .
```

Comment: printing happily :)